# @Override on method in subclass "appears" ignored at runtime

Tags: java, overriding

I really hope I am just missing something simple, but I am reading the following: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html .

I have two classes and one interface.  Literally the "use case" shown in this Oracle documentation page.  However, when I run a JUnit test - **only the method in the superclass gets called**  and that method has the simple default that I don't want called:

The interface contains this method signature:

```
public interface RecordServiceInterface {
    List<String> searchRecords(String id) throws ServiceException;
}
```

The superclass which implements the interface contains this method with a default - Eclipse IDE inserts this when it finds a missing method not implemented by the implementing class.

```
public class RecordService implements RecordServiceInterface {
    public List<String> searchRecords(String id) throws ServiceException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

At runtime, only the above is called as I step through the debugger... every time.

The subclass then extends the superclass and has the real implementation that one wants to override:

```
public class MyRecordService extends RecordService {
    @Override
    public List<String> searchRecords(String id) throws ServiceException {  
        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

        // ...

        return myList;
    }
}
```

I must be completely missing the point of `@Override`. During execution, it repeatedly fails to ever get into the method with the `@Override` annotation.

Comment: Can you include the source for the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that the @Override annotation does is make the compiler generate an error if there is no corresponding method anywhere in the class inheritance that could be overridden. So it is meant to make sure that your overridden method actually overrides something.

If your method from MyRecordService is not called, but the one from the RecordService class, then I would guess that the wrong object is instanciated. So what you have in front of you is an object of type RecordService, not of type MyRecordService.

Since you have not provided that part of the code, this is just a guess, based on the fact that your inheritance looks fine.

Comment: Jan - Many thanks... I found the issue and it has to do with the fact that I was tripped up by the way these classes are instantiated as you have alluded to here. The superclass I am actually using, uses a singleton pattern with a getInstance() method. That getInstance() method needs to pass the correct class argument to the synchronized() method, based on the value of one of the 2 constructor arguments passed in.  I added that logic to make that distinction and it now executes correctly. Sincere thanks for your time and input.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to mark my answer as correct, then ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`@Override` is a compile-time annotation and is used to verify that the annotated method actually overrides something from a superclass / interface. It does not influence runtime behavior.

Post the code for your test so we can get a clearer idea of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in `@Override`'s [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html), the retention policy of `@Override` is SOURCE. In other words: it used in compile time but does not make it to the generated binary code (class file).

In particular, the SOURCE retention policy is [defined](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html#SOURCE) as:

> Annotations are to be discarded by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

`@Override` is effectively just a way to catch typos when attempting to override a `super class`' or `instance`'s method, as well as the occasional attempt to override `final` methods (by design not overridable).

The act of overriding enables a fall-thru approach to overriding method when given a choice of what to call.

For example:

```
RecordServiceInterface service = new RecordService();
RecordService service2 = new RecordService();
```

With both `service` and `service2`, the implementation from `RecordService` will be called. Now consider:

```
RecordServiceInterface service3 = new MyRecordService();
RecordService service4 = new MyRecordService();
MyRecordService service5 = new MyRecordService();
```

With `service3`, `service4`, and `service5`, the implementation from `MyRecordService` will be called.

Overriding does not replace methods for parent types unless it is part of the chain (e.g., all three of the instances created in the last block, `3` through `5`). If the instance of your `Object` does is not the type (`MyRecordService` in this case), then the method is not overridden for that instance with its behavior.  `service` and `service2` will still call `RecordService`'s implementation.

It may be more clear with another example:

```
public interface Runnable {
    void run();
}

public class RunnableA implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() { System.out.println("A"); }
}

public class RunnableB extends RunnableA {
    @Override
    public void run() { System.out.println("B"); }
}

public class RunnableC implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() { System.out.println("C"); }
}
```

You can only have an instance of any one of them, so it will only output one line per call of `instance.run()`. It depends on the implementation of the instance, and not what exists on the classpath.